# Is there "S3 range read function" that allows to read assigned byte range from AWS-S3 file?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Trying to process large file in AWS Lamba and skipping through the whole file seems a bit wasteful.
Is there a "range read" function that allows to read only predefined byte range from S3 file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  According to S3 documentation of [GET Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) in the REST API, it supports use of the HTTP Range header.

> Range
>
> Downloads the specified range bytes of an object. For more information about the HTTP Range header, go to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.

In the example syntax:

```
GET /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Authorization: authorization string (see Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4))
Range:bytes=byte_range
```

Popular S3 client libraries, such as the [AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) provide convenient client-side APIs for specifying the range information.

Comment: I see all over that it's not possible? Do you know if it is recently added?

Comment: @olekb , I'm not certain when it was added, but I know it was usable at least since early 2016.  My experience is using it in Apache Hadoop in the [`S3AInputStream`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AInputStream.java#L154-L155) class.